# HttpError pages not working properly after Windows server 2012 restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I am checking if a person is in a distribution list or group to authenticate else set 401 status code to response. Using these custom error pages.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/ErrorPage/500.aspx">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="/ErrorPage/401.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/ErrorPage/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Under System.WebServer tag

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
  <remove statusCode="500" />
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <remove statusCode="401" />
  <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/ErrorPage/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/ErrorPage/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/ErrorPage/401.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

It is working properly when I deploy, getting proper error pages. But once I restart the server, it is asking for username and password to login. Even if I enter my credentials it is not logging in. when I remove the httpErrors tag, it is working. the pages are coming up as expected but custom error pages not coming up, sometime 500 error page and sometime inbuilt default 404/401 for not found and unauthorized error. What is the issue? After some period of time it is working with httpErrors, am I missing any config in IIS?